# Is there anyway to get an onscreen map?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In *Mario Kart 8* the Wii U gamepad can display a map that will show a general overview of the current course, as well as your current position, and those of your opponents on the map. It will also list all players and give some information about them.

However, I don't use the gamepad to play, and I thus I can't see any kind of map. I personally always like to have a general idea of where I am to measure how far ahead or behind I am, and without the gamepad it seems I can't.

Is there any way at all to get a map to display on the TV, so I'm not tied down the the Wii U gamepad?

<sup>***NOTE:** I'm not particularly looking to have the player list onscreen, but if that is also possible, it's worth mentioning.*</sup>

Answer (score 7):

on 27 of august 2014 Nintendo released an update for Mario Kart which includes this option:

- **Drivers will now have the option to display the course map on the TV screen during races**
- Users will be able to check out statistics such as their total number of coins accumulated, win-loss record from online play, and their most frequently selected character overall
- Users will be able to change options of others’ Mario Kart TV downloaded highlight reels, such as changing the focus to a new character or event
- The order of the menu after each race will be changed to “Next Race”, followed by “Watch Highlight Reel”
- The game will remember the most recent customised kart settings that were selected, even if the Wii U system is powered down
- Improvements to stability of connection in online play to enhance the user experience

Source: [Nintendo](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/News/2014/August/Nintendo-adds-three-Mercedes-Benz-cars-and-enhancements-to-Mario-Kart-8-from-27th-August-909198.html) itself

Comment: That's nice to see that Nintendo is listening to its fans. Well at least partially, I don't think any fan dreamed of playing a Mercedes Benz :p

Comment: Indeed they are. But still, it should have been included from the start. And free DLC is always nice imo :)

Answer (score 5):

Since 27th August 2014 and the 2.0 update, you can press (-) while racing to put the map on screen. This only works when you're using the gamepad.
This information is also displayed in the single player pause menu at the top.

<sup>It is still not possible to get the player list onscreen. I think that's fair as it would probably also display the items every player has - and showing that much information onscreen would make avoiding items too easy.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not - this was flagged up as a strange oversight in several reviews. It means in local multiplayer only the player with the gamepad can see the map, and in off-TV mode the map is also inaccessible (you can in this case tap the gamepad to back to the standard view to see the map, but in doing so you'll lose audio and have a tiny viewport for the race itself until you go back into off-TV mode. Suffice to say it's not workable in practice)